# Where slapd.conf "variables" come from?

Tags: openldap

I have freshly installed openldap via package manager. I couldn't find slapd.conf as official docs says:

```
The slapd.conf(5) file is normally installed in the /usr/local/etc/openldap directory.
```

So I use `find` to locate it at: `/usr/share/slapd/slapd.conf`

```
# Specific Directives for database #1, of type @BACKEND@:
# Database specific directives apply to this databasse until another
# 'database' directive occurs
database        @BACKEND@

# The base of your directory in database #1
suffix          "@SUFFIX@"

# rootdn directive for specifying a superuser on the database. This is needed
# for syncrepl.
# rootdn          "cn=admin,@SUFFIX@"
```

My question is what are those `@` surrounded placeholder/variables and how to change/influence them? I tried to find it in docs http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/guide.html but no luck.

Comment: This looks like a broken slapd.conf file, it those variables should be substituted at compile time by autoconf/automake before that slapd.conf was installed.

Comment: @nos Hmm, wierd I installed it on Linux Mint through apt (guess it's ubuntu/debian package anyway). `sudo find -name 'slapd.conf'` in root dir shows me two entries where one of them is in examples and is symoblic link to second one. The only real file is path I metion aleady: `/usr/share/slapd/slapd.conf`. Anyway my openldap daemon started and I was able to connect to ldap server. Just admin user is located in `dc=nodomain` what's bothered me a little.

Comment: This isn't a slapd.conf file, it is a template. The installation process should write another one for you.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, at least, these variables seem to be populated through execution of `debconf` or `dpkg-reconfigure` during (or after) installation.

However, the `slapd.conf` file is effectively obsolete.  OpenLDAP (since) 2.3 uses [`slapd-config`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/slapd-config.5.html), which makes use of a directory information tree (DIT) containing all the configuration information. `dpkg-reconfigure` now apparently does variable replacement in the ldif files managed by [`slapd-config`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/slapd-config.5.html) and used to populate this DIT.

From the [docs](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html) :

> OpenLDAP 2.3 and later have transitioned to using a dynamic runtime configuration engine, *slapd-config(5)*. *slapd-config(5)*
>   * is fully LDAP-enabled
>   * is managed using the standard LDAP operations
>   * stores its configuration data in an LDIF database, generally in the `/usr/local/etc/openldap/slapd.d` directory.
>   * allows all of slapd's configuration options to be changed on the fly, generally without requiring a server restart for the changes to take effect.

As indicated in the [OpenLDAP FAQ](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/108.html), your mileage may vary with regard to specific packaged implementations, as to where the configuration files and other artifacts are placed during install.

Using `apt-get` to install slapd on Ubuntu 16.04 results in the writing of this configuration schema to `/etc/ldap/slapd.d`

Information about making configuration changes can be found in the [`slapd-config` documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/slapd-config.5.html).

It is still possible to use the `slapd.conf` style of configuration with a [command-line option](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/guide.html#Command-Line%20Options).